# java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in evaluationEvaluation: status: 13 value: {message=Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because this document

Tags: javascript, java, android

I got Pre test error of my android app by google play. There is one error as mentioned below, can someone guide how to correct this error. For your info, I converted my website into android app using Android Studio.

Error:

```
Crash detected on 1 device during testing. Device is google Pixel 5, Android 11 (SDK 30)`

Stack trace: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in evaluationEvaluation: status: 13 value: {message=Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because this document requires 'Trusted Type' assignment.} hasMessage: true message: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because this document requires 'Trusted Type' assignment.

FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
Process: com.pearlastrotech.bookingastro, PID: 23237
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in evaluationEvaluation: status: 13 value: {message=Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because this document requires 'Trusted Type' assignment.} hasMessage: true message: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because this document requires 'Trusted Type' assignment.
    at androidx.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction$ExceptionPropagator.<init>(Web.java:2)
    at androidx.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction.doEval(Web.java:10)
    at androidx.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction.perform(Web.java:1)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.hybrid.HybridInteractionController.swipe(HybridInteractionController.java:15)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:45)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.ActionExecutor.performAction(ActionExecutor.java:4)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform.handlePerformAction(RemotePlatform.java:22)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform.messageLoop(RemotePlatform.java:59)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform.lambda$startCrawlAndWaitUntilFinished$0$androidx-test-tools-crawler-platform-RemotePlatform(RemotePlatform.java:1)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(Unknown Source:6)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in evaluationEvaluation: status: 13 value: {message=Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because this document requires 'Trusted Type' assignment.} hasMessage: true message: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because this document requires 'Trusted Type' assignment.
    at androidx.test.espresso.web.model.SimpleAtom.handleBadEvaluation(SimpleAtom.java:1)
    at androidx.test.espresso.web.model.SimpleAtom.transform(SimpleAtom.java:2)
    at androidx.test.espresso.web.model.SimpleAtom.transform(SimpleAtom.java:3)
    at androidx.test.espresso.web.action.AtomAction$3.apply(AtomAction.java:1)
    at androidx.test.espresso.web.action.AtomAction$3.apply(AtomAction.java:2)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bl.f.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:1)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bl.f.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:2)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bl.g.run(AbstractTransformFuture.java:9)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bl.i.execute(DirectExecutor.java:1)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bl.a.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bl.a.complete(AbstractFuture.java:11)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bl.a.set(AbstractFuture.java:2)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bl.ad.set(SettableFuture.java:1)
    at androidx.test.espresso.web.action.AtomAction$1.setResult(AtomAction.java:1)
    at androidx.test.espresso.web.action.AtomAction$2.run(AtomAction.java:1)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bl.i.execute(DirectExecutor.java:1)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bl.a.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bl.a.complete(AbstractFuture.java:11)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bl.a.set(AbstractFuture.java:2)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bl.f.setResult(AbstractTransformFuture.java:1)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bl.g.run(AbstractTransformFuture.java:12)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bl.i.execute(DirectExecutor.java:1)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bl.a.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bl.a.complete(AbstractFuture.java:11)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.bl.a.set(AbstractFuture.java:2)
    at androidx.test.espresso.web.action.JavascriptEvaluation$ValueCallbackFuture.onReceiveValue(JavascriptEvaluation.java:1)
    at X6.a(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.apk-stable-410410683:1)
    at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.w(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.apk-stable-410410683:1)
    at xr.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Have you managed to find any solution for that one?

Comment: I tested on virtual google Pixel 5, Android 11 (SDK 30) device but didn't find the issue, so I have released my app BookingAstro in open testing. It's draft version is available now in Google Play store for anyone to download, so far no issues reported.

Comment: I don't expect to see the error on a real device... Because androidx.test.espresso.web.* and androidx.test.tools.crawler were the crash seems to start are part of the automatic tool. The thing is what is the problem